# Mat table with Server side pagination - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7, mat-table

I'm working on a generic mat-table where we can pass data to that table component, which will show data to the user & should handle server side pagination.

When service is being called from the same table component it's working fine,

But when emitting an event using output event emitter from table to parent component when paginator changes, then that event should call the method should call the service which will fetch next page records and pass it to table component where user will be able to see the next set of records.

Table component

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
      merge(this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          const obj = {
            pageNumber: this.paginator.pageIndex,
            pageSize: this.paginator.pageSize,
          };
          this.pageEvent.emit(obj); --> emitting event using event emiiter

          return [];
        }),
        map((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.tableData = data;

          return data;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          return observableOf([]);
        }),
        )
        .subscribe((data: any) => {

         });
       }
```

### app comopnent HTML

```
<app-table [displayedColumns]="data" [tableData]="tableData" 
 (pageEvent)="paginator($event)"></app-table>
```

### app comonent ts

```
paginator(event)
      {
       console.log(event)
       this.pageCount=event.pageNumber+1;
       this.getData(this.pageCount)
      }
```

Thanks in Advance

stackblitz :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yr45pl
Angular example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/mgjkylrpgjp

Comment: Could you try and explain this a little bit better? Are you looking to listen to an event in another component?

Comment: @Max I'm able to listen to page change event from table and able to pass the data to other component, with the received data, I'll hit a service and fetch data which will be send again back to the table component and update table with new data. Finally. its nothing but a mat table with server side pagination , where table data is passed from another component. U can go through stackbliiz, material example as provided